# Changing/setting div height with JS if content is too long

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I have a div containing text. The text can vary in length from time to time. If the content is long enough to increase the div's height to more than say, 9em, I'd like to set the div's height to 9em. The div will already have overflow: hidden applied to it via css. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the CSS `max-height` property. No JS needed. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/jc8tY/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for JS for this.

Set the `max-height` to be  your desired height+the 9em you want.
If the text is too long to fit to the max height then you can add `overflow-y` to auto as well as `word-wrap`.

Check the **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/B33Z8/)**

Also if you want this to work on our...'favourite' browser you will need this:

```
/* sets max-height for IE6 */
_height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 149 ? "150px" : "auto" );
```

Hope this helps